# Ext MVC does not load all folders and source files

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm new to Ext and it's my first contact with this framework and I'm creating java web app. Here is my folder structure:

```
 src
 --main
   --webapp
     --index
       --application
         --controller
           --Index.js
         --model
         --store
         --view
           --MainPanel.js
       --Index.js
     --resources
     --WEB-INF
     --Index.jsp
```

Here is webapp/Index/Index.js

```
     Ext.application({
        name: 'Spring_Ext',
        appFolder: '/index/application',

        controllers: [
       'Index'
    ]
    });
```

And here is webapp/index/application/controller/Index.js

```
      Ext.define('Spring_Ext.controller.Index',{
           extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

          views: ['MainPanel'],

           init: function(){
           ....
            }
          ....
        });
```

When I run it on tomcat in chrome I get error saying it cannot found(404)
GET http://localhost:8081/index/application/controller/Index.js?_dc=1425849848988                             ext-all-debug.js:6262

and when looking in source tab in chrome developer in index folder there isn't application folder with MVC structure, but only Index.js.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because at the index.js level of your directory structure you are already in /index/application/

Extjs is now looking for the same path and cannot find it. Instead just specify '/' for you appFolder config. You might even not need to set this as it may default to this already

Answer (score 0):

No need for appFolder.  And in your source tab there is no application folder with mvc because  your controller hasn't loaded successfully. Try giving the whole path of MainPanel in our controller like this 
Views: Spring_Ext.view.MainPanel